# How to display search results MVC

Tags: java, html, sql

I'm a beginner and I came across an anomaly that I cant comprehend. From my point of view everything seems to be fine but I keep getting the same empty response when I perform a search in my MVC WebApp.

Take a look at my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**MY CONTROLLER**

```
@Controller
public class ControllerACP {

@RequestMapping("/search")
    public String Homea(Model model, @RequestParam(name = "query") String search) {
        
        model.addAttribute("clients", clientRepository.search(search));
        System.out.println(clientRepository.search(search)); // TO DISPLAY CONTENT ON CONSOLE
        System.out.println(search); // ALSO DISPLAY CONTENT ON CONSOLE
        return "search";
            
    }
}
```

**MY REPOSITORY**

```
public interface ClientRepository extends CrudRepository<Client, Integer> {

    @Query(value =  "select * from client where name LIKE ('%:?%')", nativeQuery = true)
    Iterable <Client> search(String search);
}
```

**MY HTML FILE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>SEARCH</title>
<meta content="Dashboard" property="og:title">
<meta content="Dashboard" property="twitter:title">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
<meta content="Webflow" name="generator">
<link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/webflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/ui-login-teste.webflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="w-container">
  <h1>Search results</h1>
    <form action="/search" class="w-form">
      <input type="search" class="w-input" autofocus="true" maxlength="256" name="query" placeholder="Search…" id="search">
      <input type="submit" value="Search" class="w-button">
    </form>
 </div>
      
<div class="w-container" th:each="client, interator: ${clients}">
 <a th:href="@{/crud-cliente/pagina-do-cliente/{id}(id=${client.id})}" class="table-content-link w-inline-block">
<div class="valida-table-field foto" >
<div class="table-image-wrapper avatar" th:style="'background-image: url('+@{${'/uploads/' + client.foto}}+')'"></div>
</div>
<div class="valida-table-field nome-admin"  >
   <div class="_20px" th:text="${client.name}">Nome Completo</div>
</div>
<div class="valida-table-field categoria _6">
   <div class="_20px">[[${client.phone}]]</div>
</div>
<div class="valida-table-field categoria _6">
   <div class="_20px">[[${client.email}]]</div>
</div>
<div class="valida-table-field categoria _6">
   <div class="_20px">[[${client.creation_date}]]</div>
</div>
</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you debug your code and run the query separately in SSMS. Then alter your query and finalize the one where you get your desired output.

Your query should have the searched text between %%. Something Like

```
@Query(value =  "select * from client where name LIKE ('%"+ searchedText +"%')", nativeQuery = true)
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query:

```
@Query(value =  "select * from client where name LIKE :search", nativeQuery = true)
Iterable <Client> search(@Param("search") String search);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still returns the same response.